# golang docker build fails for autogenerated proto package

Tags: docker, go, proto

I am trying to build a docker image and my build is failing with an error where it is not able to find the auto-generated proto package.

```
cannot find module providing package example.io/grpc/test: import lookup disabled by -mod=readonly
```

Here is the snippet of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.17

ENV GOFLAGS=-mod=readonly
WORKDIR /app
# Copy the Go Modules manifests
COPY go.mod go.mod
COPY go.sum go.sum
COPY grpc grpc
COPY src src

RUN apk add --virtual --update --no-cache protoc
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/go/pkg/mod \
    --mount=type=ssh,id=developer go mod download &&\
     go get -v google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go && \
     go get -v google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
RUN protoc --go_out=./grpc --go-grpc_out=./grpc ./grpc/test.proto
RUN go build main.go
```

Generation of proto files is not the issue. When other files in src use import "example.io/grpc/test" is where the error occurs.

However, if I

- Use the same protoc command before docker build such that grpc/test/test.pb.go and grpc/test/test_grpc.pb.go are generated
- Use 'COPY grpc grpc' in the Dockerfile such that even the generated files in grpc directory is copied in the docker env
- go build works and the Docker image is successfully created.

I have tried to change directory permissions for the autogenerated test directory, used GOFLAGS="", GO111MODULE=on etc. Nothing seems to help.

Appreciate any help..

/M

**EDIT 1: Structure of my project**

```
- Makefile
- Dockerfile
- src
  - zxy.go - this import example.io/grpc/test
- main.go
- go.mod
  - module example.io
- go.sum
- grpc
  - test.proto
```

Comment: What the structure of your project ? Can you share sources ? Do you have `option go_package = ...` ?

Comment: What specific details are you looking for? I don't have have `option go_package`. Where is that specified?  The problem seems to be how go sees subdirectory packages are read from within docker environment...

Comment: If `zxy.go` imports `example.io/grpc/test` so `*.pb.go` file generated by protoc must be in the `grpc/test` folder, is it right ? Add `RUN ls -la grpc/test` after `RUN protoc ...` and before `RUN go build ...`

Comment: Yes, the 2 generated files are there. The files have first lines as 'package test'

Comment: When I test this (after fixing the `Dockerfile` - e.g. `FROM golang:1.17-alpine`) the generated files are put into `/app/grpc/example.io/grpc/test` (but I had to make assumptions as you have not provided a `.proto`; I used `option go_package = "example.io/grpc/test";`). A good way of diagnosing this kind of issue is to comment out the line causing the error (and everything below) then start a shell using the image (e.g. `docker run -it IMAGEHASH  /bin/sh`) and running the command there.

Comment: I was having `RUN --mount=target=.,source=.,rw go build main.go`. I removed the mount option and my docker image built fine. Not sure, why that was causing the issue.